# Change tick size on ylabel matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've some issue working in a graph, I got this code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import rcParams

    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 12
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    yTicks = [0.5, 0.7, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 10.0, 20, 30, 50, 70, 100, 200, 300]
    xTicks = [0, 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000, 3600]

    ax.set_xticks(xTicks)
    ax.set_yticks(yTicks)

    plt.show()
```

And gives me this graph
[image: this graph]

Is there anyway that the ylabel could be changed for one like this

[image: on this photo?]

Comment: Plot your data and set `plt.yscale('log')`

Comment: I've already tried it but now i got only 2 ticks 10⁰ and 10¹

Comment: `plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="-")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show logarithmically spaced grid lines at all ticks on a log-log plot using Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590905/how-do-i-show-logarithmically-spaced-grid-lines-at-all-ticks-on-a-log-log-plot-u)

Comment: That's just for the grid isn't it? I'm interested in the size between the ticks :/

Comment: It's log scale, you don't get to choose the spacing between the ticks.

Comment: [How to show minor tick labels on log-scale with Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887920/how-to-show-minor-tick-labels-on-log-scale-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved it! by changing first the yscale to log and then setting the ticks with `set_yticks` and the changing the labels with `set_yticklabels` an gave me  [image: this]. Thanks to everyone on the comments <3